# WPF memory leak after creating window in another thread

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, thread-safety

I am creating window in another thread. After closing the thread some of the resources window is not released from the memory. Because of this growing counter GDI Objects and User Objects in windows task manager. Graphics that not released are font and region. I haven't idea what is going on...

```
public class WaitingWindowManager
{
    private Thread thread;
    private bool canAbortThread = false;
    private Window waitingWindow;

    public void BeginWaiting()
    {
        this.thread = new Thread(this.RunThread);
        this.thread.IsBackground = true;
        this.thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        this.thread.Start();
    }

    public void EndWaiting()
    {
        if (this.waitingWindow != null)
        {
            this.waitingWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { this.waitingWindow.Close(); }));
            while (!this.canAbortThread) { };
        }

        this.thread.Abort(); 
    }

    public void RunThread()
    {
        this.waitingWindow = new Window();
        this.waitingWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(waitingWindow_Closed);
        this.waitingWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    void waitingWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.canAbortThread = true;
    }
}
```

And call :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            WaitingWindowManager waitingWindowManager = new WaitingWindowManager();
            waitingWindowManager.BeginWaiting();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread.Join(5000);
            waitingWindowManager.EndWaiting();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your Closed eventhandler in your waitingWindow_Closed Event.  It is causing your window to not be disposed. If you manually add events you need to make sure you remove them when finished.

I also noticed another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071704/how-to-avoid-massive-memory-leaks-on-wpf-on-net-3-5) that was pertaining to memory leaks in wpf. It referenced this [article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/06/WPF-Memory-Leaks) maybe this will help you.

Comment: Not work. I have a leak memory in this case too.  public void RunThread()
        {
            Window waitingWindow = new Window();
           // waitingWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(waitingWindow_Closed);
            waitingWindow.ShowDialog();
        }

Comment: What I did was this. I used the suggestion by Femaref and removed the handler. I does allow the new window to be disposed.        void waitingWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.waitingWindow.Closed -= new EventHandler (waitingWindow_Closed);
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown(); 
            this.canAbortThread = true;
        }    If this is still leaking what objects are being leaked

Comment: I can't understand. Assume that eventhandler prevents us from disposing object. 
And if I add 

void waitingWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
 this.waitingWindow.Closed -= new EventHandler(waitingWindow_Closed);
 this.canAbortThread = true; 
} 
 
it's must to resolve the problem. But it's not work.
Moreover, if you haven't the handler in general, the result is the same one : leak of the memory

Comment: RE: If this is still leaking what objects are being leaked

The window (waitingWindow) is destroyed, this can be seen in memory profiler, 
but the object of the WaitingWindowManager class can't be destroyed. 
And such behavior appears only after creating WPF window in the thread

Comment: In the memory profiler that I am using. It is showing the WaitingWindowManager class being destroyed. SciTech .Net Memory Profiler(http://memprofiler.com).

Answer (score 1):

Add `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();` in your closing code. That should take care of any leaking memory.

Comment: It's WPF not windows forms at first and at second I did not create
gdi ojects

Comment: It's not work. The window (waitingWindow) is destroyed, this can be seen
in memory profiler, but the object of the WaitingWindowManager class can't be destroyed. And such behavior appears only after creating WPF window in the thread

Comment: @Femaref After hours of digging, this saved my butt! In my case, I was creating a WPF Window from within an STA Thread. Adding this to the closing event of the WPF window did the trick.