# How to avoid massive memory leaks on WPF on .Net 3.5?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

When I run my app targeted to .Net 3.5 it has massive memory leaks. 50mb every time I assign a UserControl to a local ref. I only ever create one instance of each UserControl. If I compile and run the same code targeted to .Net 4.0 everything runs fine hovering around the 50mb mark.

Is this a known isue with 3.5? I.e. it's not usable in prod?

/My clients only have 3.5 and won't be moving to 4.0 for awhile so i don't have the easy option

Comment: Sorry please explain? The code is fine on .Net 4.0

Comment: And what are you using to determine memory usage? If it's Task Manager, you should know that it is very inaccurate to use for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Memory Leak Hotfixes for WPF 3.5 SP1** 
http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/06/WPF-Memory-Leaks

In particular, have a look at these two hotfixes, which have been fixed in .NET 4.0, but are available as hotfixes to users of .NET 3.5:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967634

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967328

Comment: Nice link. However, these seem to mostly refer to short-term memory pressure with WeakReferences.

Comment: Damn you crapy WPF! Thanks that seems to have fixed the problem. But I can't ask all my clients to apply these hot fixes. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: @DayTwo: I doubt it; the fixes have to be deployed.  If you have an automatic update function for your software, you can incorporate it into that.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think it is a leak, and not just memory that hasn't been garbage collected yet? Is there some impact outside of a number in a profiler that you are concerned with? If not, why worry. Would you rather your program used available memory or would you rather it used CPU cycles recovering unused objects?

Comment: Because after many gui interactions it throws an OutOfMemory exception. GC never reclaims hence leak.

Comment: I would like to see the code that's doing that. It's much more likely a bug in the code than the Framework... and 4.0 is just handling that bug better.